# How to remove timestamp with the date using sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have date with timestamp eg: `2019-05-06 00:00:00` 
I want this date without timestamp

output:  `2019-05-06`

Answer (score 3):

use `date()` function

```
select date("2019-05-06 00:00:00" )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way in MySQL

```
SELECT CONVERT("2019-05-06 00:00:00", date);
```

In MSSQL same can be done in this way

```
select convert(varchar, your_date, 23)
```

You can get help from [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/)

Comment: *"You can do it in this way"* No you can't as this is SQL Server (MSSQL) syntax, the question is about MySQL..

Comment: The valid MySQL syntax would be `SELECT CONVERT("2019-05-06 00:00:00", date);`

Comment: Yes in MSSQL can be done in the way, but in question not mentioned exactly. I'll leave my answer here, for other people help.

Comment: @RaymondNijland you can update my answer, I'll accept that.

Comment: @AsadAliChoudhry, this question is directly tagged with mysql, not mssql

Comment: *"Yes in MSSQL can be done in the way, but in question not mentioned exactly"* The question is about MySQL not MSSQL.. The sql tag is about ANSI/ISO SQL not SQL Server (MSSQL) on this website.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MySQL function `DATE_FORMAT()`

```
DATE_FORMAT(%Y-%m-%d)
```

More information is [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp)

Comment: We don't like w3schools ([w3fools](https://www.w3fools.com/)) documentation link with a reason, please link to the official documention MySQL's [DATE_FORMAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)